# I am trying to signup a user in android using parse with the help of back4app dashboard.But I am getting the i/o failure

Tags: android, parse-platform

Stack trace:

```
com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure
om.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:289)
com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:144)
com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:138)
com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:839)
com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.parse.com": No address associated with hostname
com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:125)
02-05 11:20:35.636 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
02-05 11:20:35.636 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
02-05 11:20:35.636 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
02-05 11:20:35.636 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
02-05 11:20:35.636 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
02-05 11:20:35.636 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
02-05 11:20:35.636 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:346)
02-05 11:20:35.636 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
02-05 11:20:35.636 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:247)
02-05 11:20:35.636 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
02-05 11:20:35.636 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
02-05 11:20:35.636 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:257)
02-05 11:20:35.636 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
02-05 11:20:35.637 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
02-05 11:20:35.637 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseURLConnectionHttpClient.executeInternal(ParseURLConnectionHttpClient.java:51)
02-05 11:20:35.637 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:158)
02-05 11:20:35.637 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram.MainActivity$ParseLogInterceptor.intercept(MainActivity.java:29)
02-05 11:20:35.637 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:154)
02-05 11:20:35.637 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseDecompressInterceptor.intercept(ParseDecompressInterceptor.java:30)
02-05 11:20:35.637 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:147)
02-05 11:20:35.637 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParsePlugins$1.intercept(ParsePlugins.java:115)
02-05 11:20:35.637 19442-19442/com.example.rishabhbassi.instagram W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:147)
```

I am using parse to register a new user but it is giving a i/o failure request exception.I am using API26 and i have also tried to include dependency parse version 11.0 but still getting the error

My code for Signing up User is :

```
    ParseUser user=new ParseUser();
    user.setUsername("rishabhbassi");
    user.setPassword("rishabbassi");

    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
                Log.i("signup","Succcessfull");
            }
            else{
                Log.i("signup","failed");
                Log.i("message",e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this error:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.parse.com":
>   No address associated with hostname

I can tell that you didn't initialized the parse android SDK ahead of creating the user. If you will go to the [Getting Started](http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#getting-started) section in parse Android SDK docs you will see that before performing any CRUD operation via the SDK you must initialize it first. Usually the initialization should be done in your Android application object (unless you have a different architecture) the following way:

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import android.app.Application;

public class App extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
      .applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
      .server("YOUR_PARSE_SERVER_ENDPOINT")
      .build()
    );
  }
}
```

By looking at the code above you can immediatly understand that you need to provide (at least) 2 things:

- Your application ID (mandatory value for any parse-server based app)
- Server URL - here you need to provide your Back4App endpoint where your parse-server is running on. If you develop locally you will need to provide **localhost** with the specific port where your parse-server running on.